# Different kind of stamina problem

Tags: unity, c#

I have an object that I interact with physics via:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PhysicsBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }
}
```

However, now I want to add a "stamina" bar, so if the user holds any of the movement keys which affect the rb, the stamina bar starts depleting. Once empty, the user can no longer affect the rb with the movement buttons.

I've tried viewing some of the classic stamina bar sprint options but they don't use the rigidbody physics like I am doing, so I wonder if anyone knows how I do it in my example?

Comment: It's not clear where the issue lies. Why wouldn't a simple `if` work? `if ( stamina > 0) rb.AddForce (movement * speed);`

Comment: I'm just very new to coding and unsure when I'm writing my own code, but I think I understand what you're getting at, but I'm not sure if I could implant it myself. I assume I'd make a public float called stamina and then only activate the addforce if it's above 100. But how do I make the drain function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is roughly how I'd do it to manage the stamina; the idea is to make the player move and consume stamina only if there is stamina left. If there is no stamina and the player tries to move, no stamina is recovered. The only way to recover stamina is to not request for movement.

This code is not tested and might not compile in Unity, view it as pseudo code.

```
public class PhysicsBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    public float maxStamina; // from the editor
    public float staminaReconveryRate; // from the editor
    public float staminaDrainRate; // from the editor
    private float currentStamina;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        currentStamina = maxStamina;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        // player requests to move
        if ( moveHorizontal != 0.0 || moveVertical != 0.0 )
        {
            // and has stamina
            if (maxStamina > 0.0)
            {
                // let them move and consume stamina, and make sure there is no less stamina
                // than the minimum (0)
                Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0, moveVertical);

                rb.AddForce (movement * speed);

                currentStamina = Mathf.Max( currentStamina - staminaDrainRate, 0.0)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // the player does not request to move, so we restore the stamina, and make sure
            // they don't go over the max.
            currentStamina = Mathf.Min( currentStamina + staminaReconveryRate, maxStamina );
        }
    }
}
```

For the visual implementation of it, I don't have a clue. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a spin. What do you mean when you write "from the editor"?

Comment: Ah, just that it's going to be a tunable value :)

Comment: Ok, in the "staminaDrainRate = max( currentStamina - staminaDrainRate, 0.0);" is the max supposed to be a mathf function of sorts, because I can't see what it denotes.

Also what is the joystickdeadband perimeter for?

Comment: Yes, `max` should return the maximun value of the two values passed. Same idea for `min`. Not sure if such a thing exists in Unity. Alternatively you can do it with a couple of `if` :p

Comment: Ok thanks, I fixed the min and max code but I'm still wondering what JoyStickDeadband is? Never heard this expression.

Comment: @Paze The deadband is roughly the range of values close to 0 that are interpreted as 0. I think it's already taken into consideration by Unity though, according to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nathalievangelist/2014/12/16/joystick-input-in-unity-using-xbox360-controller/) article.

Comment: @Paze I updated the answer: added the 'real' methods for min and max. I also removed the concept of deadband because it seems that Unity manages it from the settings, so it's transparent for the code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `currentStamina = Mathf.Max(...)` instead of `staminaDrainRate` ?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Yeah, edited, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. Luckily I caught the small bugs and made it work. The code works exactly like I want it to.